# How to Migrate from netcoreapp1.0 to netcoreapp1.1 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, asp.net, migration, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded to .NET Core 1.1  from .Net Core 1.0
I already have projects using .Net Core 1.0
How do I successfully migrate. 
because I have tried using

```
dotnet migrate
```

to migrate it was successfull but when I tried running

```
dotnet restore
```

I had a long verbose of errors being displayed as shown below

```
1.0.0/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc.1.0.0.nupkg'.                                                                                                  [1320/1825]
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.1.0.3' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer/1.0.3/microsoft.as
pnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer.1.0.3.nupkg'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.1.0.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframew
orkcore/1.0.2/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.1.0.2.nupkg'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.1.0.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions/1.0.2/mi
crosoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions.1.0.2.nupkg'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.json/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.localization/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools.1.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.to
ols/1.0.0/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools.1.0.0.nupkg'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.httpoverrides/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't resolve host name
[0] 0:[tmux]*Z
```

What Do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have solved it
After running

```
dotnet migrate
```

Run

```
dotnet restore
```

Oh I almost forgot

## Edit the webprojectfile.csproj file

That is instead of

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>webproj</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>webproj</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication-0799fe3e-6eaf-4c5f-b40e-7c6bfd5dfa9a</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Update the file to reflect the netcore latest version
as shown below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>webproj</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>webproj</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication-0799fe3e-6eaf-4c5f-b40e-7c6bfd5dfa9a</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

which is to change this line

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

and

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

## Edit: Please DO Not eliminate or rename the

"appsettings.json" file

## Leave the appsettings.json as it acts as environment file settings or .env in PHP. :)

Also in the Startup.cs file

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // comment this line 
                // builder.AddUserSecrets();
                // Use this instead   
               builder.AddUserSecrets("myusersecretAddUserSecrets"); // where myusersecretAddUserSecrets is your secret key or ID 
            }
```

Then you can now rerun the following

```
dotnet restore
```

then

```
dotnet build
```

then

```
dotnet run
```

Your Application Should Be Running without errors By NOW!! Hopefully. :)